# Importing a .csv or .xlsx file into mysql DB using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, excel, csv, intellij-idea

YES, it sounds like a duplicate.

I'm practicing abit of Java on Intellij and tried writing a program to import a .xls excel file into a mysql database. Duplicate question, yes, but trawling the internet didnt yield much.

My code below currently does the job of importing any xls file perfectly. Unfortunately, it doesnt do anything for a .csv file nor an xlsx file.

When i try with a .csv file, the following error is thrown:

```
Invalid header signature; read 0x6972702C74786574, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
```

When a xlsx file is used, the following is instead thrown as an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:152)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:302)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:85)
at FileExport.main(FileExport.java:21)
```

My code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;




public class FileExport {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {

        Class forName = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = null;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false", "root", "root");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/Users/User/Desktop/Email/Test.xls");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
        Workbook workbook;
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);
            String text = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            int price = (int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();


            String sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (text, price) VALUES('" + text + "','" + price + "')";
            pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setString(1, text);
            pstm.setInt(2, price);
            pstm.execute();
            System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
        }
        con.commit();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions on how to tweak this code to import .csv or xlsx files are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could read the file and parse it yourself, without using POIFS. Parsing .csv is quite easy. Just read the file line by line, and split the line at the delimiter character (it's not always a comma).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you explain a little bit what difference there is from parsing and this? I've seen it online in my googling adventures but cant really get what parsing the file actually does.

Comment: @PeterBruins, it is a bad advice. CSV has many edge cases. http://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/
Also it is not too related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use PreparedStatement as it was intended for:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (text, price) VALUES(?, ?)";       
pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstm.setString(1, text);
pstm.setInteger(2, text)
pstm.execute();
```

I guess it doesn't work because there is some punctuation in your `text`.
Also it is prone to SQL-injection.

Also you should close your closeable objects with `try-with-resources` or `finally` (if you stuck to java version prior version 7), as it done here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516076/3323777

**EDIT**: ah yes, the empty catch block as Alex said. Don't do that, either.

**EDIT2**:

> Apache POI was never designed to call on CSV files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087984/3323777

There is another project for CSV at Apache:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: I did as both of you said, but now there's a new error that i dont quite understand: Invalid header signature; read 0x6972702C74786574, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Comment: Indeed, so i was researching abit and thought of this: convert the file tio xls(yes old format) then use the current code to import to mysql?  Basically combine the two codes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189308/convert-csv-to-xls-in-java

Comment: IMHO it would be more clunky than use a CSV library for that. BTW, please feel free to accept any answer which (and if) helped to solve your question (a checkmark on the left side of an answer under the vote arrows).

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the "Import rows" messages which prove that you actually have some rows to import?

Also the reason for not seeing any errors might be a "catch" block which does nothing. Add any output inside and observe new results, i.e.

```
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and indeed this error popped out:  Invalid header signature; read 0x6972702C74786574, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Comment: Then I suggest you consider replacing POIFS with some other solution. Or do it yourself. Should it be a big deal? Open a file, read line by line, split every line using comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked for read from .csv

```
public class FileExport {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

try {

    Class forName = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = null;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false", "root", "root");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/Users/User/Desktop/Email/Test.csv");
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
     String row = reader.readLine();
     String text = row.split(";")[0];
     String price = row.split(";")[1];
     reader.close();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (text, price) VALUES('" + text + "','" + price + "')";
        pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.execute();
        System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
    }
    con.commit();
    pstm.close();
    con.close();
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

}

Comment: There is something weird in this code, e.g. the variables `con`, `pstm`, and `input` are used out of their scope. You may want to re-validate the code.

Comment: I took the template from the question.

Comment: Also I listened that at some places use transfer file line-by-line to table, then from table content like param1;param2;param3 parse by sql like: 
    `SELECT           
    TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,0,INSTR(CON,CHR(59))-1)) param1,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,1)+1,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)-INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,1)-1)) param2,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)+1,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,3)-INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)-1)) param3,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,3)+1)) param4  
FROM ( SELECT ROW_CONTENT CON FROM CONTENT_TABLE WHERE DOC_NAME="doc.csv")`

Comment: *I took the template from the question.* - well, that template was at least compilable, your code isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'poi-ooxml' for creating a Workbook object, its gradle dependency signature is provided below:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.14'
```

Below code may help you

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/User/Desktop/Email/Test.xls");
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```