# List and map data of csv file using java

Tags: java, csv, filereader

In relation to my question - [List Map data in excel using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403394/list-map-data-in-excel-using-java), is there a way where I can convert the code to read csv file with same output as a result

This is the sample csv data:

[image]

My expected Output would be like this:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You can use OpenCSV library.

Comment: The expected output looks like the result of calling `toString()` on a collection containing the rows as parsed object of a class which implements a `toString()` itself

Comment: Post text rather than images, wherever possible, on this site.

Answer (score 0):

No `Map` involved here, just a `List`.

You have not explained the semantics. But it appears that you simply need to define a `Person` class (or a `Person` [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in modern Java) with five properties named in first row.

Read your CSV row by row, constructing a `Person` object for each row. I suggest using a library to help with the CSV parsing, such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](http://commons.apache.org/csv). Add each new `Person` object to a `List` such as `ArrayList`.

Call `toString` on your `List` to generate output text. If you want a different format, loop the `Person` objects in the list to generate your own text of desired format.

All of this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.